# Install ca-certificates from chef gives wrong output

Tags: chef-infra

I tried installing "ca-certificates" in a centos machine. The output said "up to date"
and then I tried to update the ca-trust keyring using chef. It threw an error: `No such file or directory update-ca-trust force-enable`.

After that I tried installing the certificate by the execute resource `yum install -y ca-certificates` and it was installed and the ca-trust was updated.

Why was chef unable to install the package first and say it was updated?

Here is what I had written in the recipe

```
#Installing CA certificate
package "ca-certificates" do #also tried with yum_package
   action :install
   flush_cache [:before]
end
```

Comment: Show your recipe and chef run log, we do no divination here.

Comment: Still no log from the chef run. And no view on your execute resource either. It's hard to tell what's going wrong without input.